# Relay "sticking"

Tags: relay

We are experiencing a problem where the mechanical switch of a SPST NO relay ([COTO 9007-05-01](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Coto%20Technology%20PDFS/9000_Spartan_Series.pdf)) is not opening back up when the coil is de-energized. Current keeps flowing through the switch until we give the relay a (somewhat gentle) flick.

We measured voltage and current on an o-scope (a Tektronix current probe for the current), and everything appears to be in order: On/Off voltage connected to coil appears good, On/Off current through the coil appears good, on-current through the switch well below rated current, open voltage across the switch well below the rated voltage, no unreasonable spikes, the coil has a fly-back diode installed...

We even replicated our setup with different everything (including relays) and got the same results.

Any suggestions on what to do/check?

Comment: What is the measured voltage across the relay when you attempt to turn it off?

Comment: A link to the relay datasheet would also be helpful.

Comment: I didn't actually measure the closed-switch voltage...

Comment: data sheet: http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Coto%20Technology%20PDFS/9000_Spartan_Series.pdf  we are using the COTO 9007-05-01

Comment: BTW: 28V open switch voltage, 5V coil voltage, 100mA current through switch when closed.

Comment: I meant to say the "relay coil" in my comment above. Looks like you have to drop below 0.4V for the relay to turn off. Any chance your circuit is holding the coil voltage above that? Can you post a schematic?

Comment: Pretty confident we're driving the coil well below 0.4V. I had the scope on 1V/div and it looked like a flat 0V, so it would have been obvious on the o-scope if it was above 0.4. Also, I meant to say that the flyback diode is built into the relay (the -01 in the part name indicates this), and yes I did verify that have the correct polarity across the coil too.

Comment: What I was trying to ask (before I ran into technical difficulties) was if the load on the relay switch is inductive (not the relay coil), and if so, does that have a flyback diode? I am thinking of the possibility that due to contact bounce, there could be some arcing when the contacts are closing causing the sticking.

Comment: Or if the load has a high capacitance then the surge current at closure could weld the contacts together. Relays are inherently unreliable - I avoid them whenever possible...

Comment: Probably Tut or Bruce have it : something - possibly current surges - are welding the contacts shut. If you pull a failed relay apart, use a magnifier to look for unusual pitting or metal flow on the contacts. Notice the contacts can only switch 0.5A and that current includes any surge. Notice also the rated life is 100 million ops ... at 0.01A! with a "contact the makers" warning for other currents...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am in agreement with @BruceAbbott's comment, above. I suspect that although your static load current is well within the relay's capability, the surge current when it closes, probably due to charging caps and/or firing up an SMPS, is welding the contacts.  I suspect this because I have seen precisely the behaviour that you're describing, down to the sharp tap on the relay body causing the contacts to release.

My solution was to cause the device that I was switching (that was powered by an SMPS) to soft-start using an LCR network between the output of the relay and the input to the device.

If the cause of your problem is SMPS inrush current, and you have control over the SMPS, you may be able to put it into a "soft start" mode, either because it has the capability and just needs to be configured to use it.  Alternatively, try my solution.  Apologies, it was 10 years or so ago, I can't recall exactly what I used; a small series resistor (<10R) and large inductor (100uH?) and various smallish caps (1-10nF) to ground sounds vaguely familiar.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comments everyone. I will have to do some digging to find out the exact characteristics of our load (it's somewhat of a black box right now). We are speculating an inductive load right now...but we are going to try to make sure. We will try cutting a problematic one open and look for welds.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the relay is close to something that has become magnetized enough over time - because of the making and breaking of the relay's magnetic field - that its biasing the reeds OFF when they're supposed to release.

Answer (score 0):

I was US Navy (nuclear) trained and commercial power controls maintenance for over 30 years. Relays "stick."  This can be due to tight clearances, age, residual magnetism, or other aspects. See what relays are in question.  Tap "soundly" (but not too hard) with butt of a screwdriver or similar device.  Do this several times while the circuit is deenergized. Reenergize and test. This works a good percentage of the time.