# Funduino/Keyes relay board doesn't switch off relays

Tags: relay, raspberry-pi

I've build a simple set up with a Raspberry Pi and [this](https://www.modmypi.com/electronics/relays/8-channel-12v-relay-module) relay board to switch some lights. I have removed the jumper from the relay board, connected 12V to the VCC/GND pins, connected the Pi GND to the relay board's COM pin, and the GPIO pins to the relay board inputs. I connected the load to the relay's NO (normal open) connectors. When I use the gpio utility I can switch the pins on the Pi on and off; the relay board follows this, as confirmed by the LED and the load on the relays switching on and off. So far so good.

But then, after a little bit of playing around, the relays stopped switching off. The LED for the relay does switch off, but the contact stays closed; the lights connected to that relay stay on. Not all relays have the problem, and every now and then the ones who *do* have the problem work once or twice; but they don't reliably switch off.

So, if we ignore mechanical failure of the relays for a second (I doubt *all* relays on a board would have the same defect...), what could cause this behaviour? I mean, when I remove the signal from the relay board, the optocoupler on the board would stop conducting, the signal would disappear on the 'other side' of the optocoupler, and all relays should switch back to 'open', right? But even if I unplug the Pi, the relays stay closed! And when I unplug everything (the Pi, the power to the relay board, the power to the load) and replug, the relays that were stuck *still* are closed.

What further steps can I take to debug this? Thanks.

Comment: What load were you switching and what is the spec of the relays used?

Comment: The loads are 2 to 4 e27 sockets into which are screwed led lights of about 5w each. (These are 'filament bulb replacement' lamps, so working on 230v ac). So between 10 and 20w per relay @ 230v ac. The data sheet for the relay is on the link I posted, under the second tab. It seems to be a mechanical relay, I imderstood ssd relays are tricky wrt inductive loads but I think that doesn't apply to my situation. Also, when everything is unplugged and I measure across the contacts with a multimeter, the relay is still in the closed position. Thanks.

Comment: So, off the top of your head you don't know the contact ratings then?

Comment: I have the same board (unused) marked ver:8R1A 12/03/14. The relays are marked "Songle 10A SRD-12VDC-SL-C" A [datasheet](https://www.ghielectronics.com/downloads/man/20084141716341001RelayX1.pdf) says the relays need 12V but the same PCB design is used for both [5V](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/8-channel-relay-board)  and [12V](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/index.php?product_id=1187) relay modules. The vendor description says *"It only requires a voltage of approx 1.0V to switch the inputs on but can handle input voltages up to 12V. This makes it ideal for both 5V and 3.3V devices."*

Comment: Mechanical failure could mean manufacturing defect or in this case user operation failure.

Comment: Thanks all for your thoughts. @Andy yes it's the relay RedGrittyBrick mentions, rated 10A - sorry didn't realize that's what you were after. I recognize many of the symptoms described, but some are different. For one, when I tap the relays, they switch back to their open position (sometimes). However, my static load is 0.061A - about what you'd expect from 20W of lights @ 220V. Yet the relays are hot to the touch after they've been switched on for a while (few hours). Also I can't imagine that a 20W load would cause a >10A initial spike, could it?

Comment: (I mean technically anything is 'possible' of course, but speaking about 'normal' loads like simple LED lights like I'm switching - but even the 500W lamp in RedGrittyBrick's answer spiked 'only' at 20A, 10x the static load) So I'm thinking there is something else wrong with the relays that is causing them to heat up like that, which in turns causes them to weld shut. But they're very common relays and the way I've hooked them up is the same everybody else on the internet does it... I don't have an oscilloscope so I can't measure any spike current myself.

Comment: Also, I rapidly switched the relay on and off about 10 times; I would imagine that if the welding shut happens because of spike currents, doing this would the worst thing to do to the relay, right? Yet it kept switching on/off no problem. It seems like problems only start once the relay has been on for some time.

Answer (score 1):

> **what could cause this behaviour?**

Welding the relay contacts together due to a high initial current.

If your lights on the load side are incandescents, they have a low resistance until the filaments heat up. So a relatively high current can pass for several milliseconds.

[image]
Image from [Lamptech](http://www.lamptech.co.uk/Documents/IN%20Starting.htm)

Note the 500W lamp has a normal operating current of around 2A but during the first five milliseconds the current is greater than 15A. Your relays are rated 10A.

> **What further steps can I take to debug this?**

Measure the current flowing in the first few milliseconds.

Hit the recalcitrant relay with a blunt object so that the mechanical shock can break the contacts free?

Take a relay apart and inspect the contacts?

---

See also

- [Relay "sticking"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/131730/2191)